# How to receive data from server and update my textview

Tags: android, sockets

guys, I'm just a newbie in android and programming, I have searched and search for examples and tutorials and I implement it on my project but now I really don't know what to do, please help me

I have a server on python and a client in Android, I have done sending CMD command to the server and the function server side will execute on what the command is and then send a message to the client. And that is now my problem is I don't know how to receive a message from the server to my Android client so far this is my code, I really hope that you can save me guys, thank you very much

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button  btnUp;
    Button btnDown;
    Button btnRight;
    Button btnLeft;
    Button btnStop;
    EditText txtAddress;
    Socket myAppSocket = null;
    public  static  String wifiModuleIp = "";
    public static int wifiModulePort = 0;
    public static  String CMD ="0";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        txtnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_reply_from_server);
        btnUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUp);
        btnDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDown);
        btnRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRight);
        btnLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLeft);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        txtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IPadd);

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIpandPort();
                CMD = "Stop";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_increase_servo = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_increase_servo.execute();
            }
        });

        btnUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIpandPort();
                CMD = "Up";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_increase_servo = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_increase_servo.execute();

            }
        });

        btnDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIpandPort();
                CMD = "Down";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_increase_servo = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_increase_servo.execute();

            }
        });

        btnRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIpandPort();
                CMD = "Right";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_increase_servo = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_increase_servo.execute();
            }
        });

        btnLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIpandPort();
                CMD = "Left";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_increase_servo = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_increase_servo.execute();
            }
        });
     }



    public void getIpandPort()
    {
        String iPandPort = txtAddress.getText().toString();
        Log.d("MY TEST","IP String:" + iPandPort);
        String temp[] = iPandPort.split(":");
        wifiModuleIp = temp[0];
        wifiModulePort = Integer.valueOf(temp[1]);
        Log.d("MY TEST","IP:" + wifiModuleIp);
        Log.d("MY TEST ","PORT:" + wifiModulePort);



    }

    public  class Socket_AsyncTask extends  AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        Socket socket;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
            try{
                InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(MainActivity.wifiModuleIp);
                socket = new java.net.Socket(inetAddress,MainActivity.wifiModulePort);
                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(CMD);
                dataOutputStream.close();
                socket.close();
            }catch (UnknownHostException e){e.printStackTrace();}catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            return null;

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WebSocket, data from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516404/android-websocket-data-from-server)

Comment: What is the problem? I see you write data to an outputstream. Ok. Now you only have to read from an inputstream to get the data from the server. What is the problem?

Comment: thanks so i need inputstream to read thus it also receive the message and update my textview in ui?

Answer (score 0):

You can call your server url using HTTP client. I recommend you to try [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: Also nonsense. There is no http protocol.

Comment: Don't recommend Retrofit to nwebees